# Hide <dd> and <dt> when <dd> contains specific character or a single character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML showing user responses to fields from a form on a private user profile page. The fields on the form are conditional, so many of them are never presented to the user.  The HTML is output by a system, and the dropdown fields that were never presented to the users receive "—" (em dash?) for a value, and the checkboxes that they do not check receive "No".

The system lacks a feature to recognize these fields and hide them, so I must do it with CSS or JS/JQ.  On document ready, I need to hide the DD with the "—" value and the associated parent DT.  I would also like to do this with the checkboxes that come through as "No", but the dash is much more critical.

I haven't had any success trying to tweak solutions provided in somewhat similar posts.  Thanks for any suggestions and expertise!

```html
 <dl class="request-details">
      <dt>Test Account submitted this request</dt>
               
                <dt>Status</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span class="request-status request-open" title="We are working on a response for you">
                   Open
                   </span>
                </dd>
            
                <dt>Name</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>Wayne Gretzky</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>Order Number</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>—</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>Brand</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>Brand XYZ</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>Check the box if you are trying to retrieve links or registration information.</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>No</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>Check the box if you can access the email address your software is registered to.</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>No</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>SS Product Type</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>Plus</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>SN Product Type</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>—</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>SNE Product Type</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>—</span>
                </dd>
                
                <dt>TLE Product Type</dt>
                <dd>
                   <span>—</span>
                </dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the spans, and if any of their contents are `—`, then hide the parent `dd` and previous `dt`

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '—') {
    $(this).parent('dd').addClass('hidden').prev('dt').addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<dl class="request-details">
  <dt>Test Account submitted this request</dt>

  <dt>Status</dt>
  <dd>
    <span class="request-status request-open" title="We are working on a response for you">
                   Open
                   </span>
  </dd>

  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>Wayne Gretzky</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>Order Number</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>—</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>Brand</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>Brand XYZ</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>Check the box if you are trying to retrieve links or registration information.</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>No</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>Check the box if you can access the email address your software is registered to.</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>No</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>SS Product Type</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>Plus</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>SN Product Type (hide)</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>—</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>SNE Product Type</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>—</span>
  </dd>

  <dt>TLE Product Type</dt>
  <dd>
    <span>—</span>
  </dd>
```

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for your quick assistance.  This seems to be exactly what I needed.  You expertise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains` selector

```
$('.request-details dd span:contains(—)')
        .parent().addClass('hidden')
        .prev().addClass('hidden');
```